# Rails before_filter for specific actions in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, before-filter

```
  def new
    before_filter  do 
      redirect_to "/" unless current_admin || current_company
      flash[:notice] = 'You dont have enough permissions to be here' unless current_admin || current_company

     end
    CODE CODE CODE
   end

  def edit
    before_filter  do 
      redirect_to "/" unless current_admin.id = 5
      flash[:notice] = 'You dont have enough permissions to be here' unless current_admin || current_company

     end
    CODE CODE CODE
   end
```

This is the code that I want to do, but I cant figure out how to do it right. 
What I want to achieve is to apply a before_filter rule for each of my actions. So perhaps a User can acces de INDEX action but not the EDIT action etc.
I know that the before_filter method runs a single time, and  I cannot run 4 before_filters, I'm just giving some reference because of my poor english.

You must know that I am using Devise for the current_admin and current_company methods. 
I need to apply different filters (if admin or if company.id = X) and other actions.

Thanks in advance, I am pretty stucked in here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Create in your `ApplicationController` method:

```rb
def check_privileges!
  redirect_to "/", notice: 'You dont have enough permissions to be here' unless current_admin || current_company
end
```

And then in your controller:

```rb
before_filter :check_privileges!, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :save]
```

Or

```rb
before_filter :check_privileges!, except: [:index, :show]
```

Comment: To be honest. I didn't know that your way is also acceptable.

Comment: In Rails 4+, use `before_action` instead of `before_filter`.

Comment: how do I pass a parameter to `:some_function` mentioned after `before_action`?

Comment: @ZekeDran you cannot. The only solution is to use lambda as a parameter and then you can do anything.

Comment: @Hauleth why the `!` at the end of the method name?