# Rails - dom something on specific route changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I have to implement something into an existing Ruby on Rails application.
Specifically I want to send events to Google Analytics whenever the user changes to specific routes, so I need to hook into the rails router and call a method whenever these routes are called.
How can I do that? I found that I should use a module with `before_filter` but now idea how, as my rails experience is very low...

Thanks!

Comment: if you google your question a bit you will find lots of similar questions which have been answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061373/rails-before-filter-for-specific-actions-in-controller. The rails docs are also a good place to start, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter

Comment: Thanks!
Of course I tried to google but didn't find anything useful. Maybe due to my lack of the right terms...