# How to avoid to check user status on every page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I can check a user and to log out on some condition.
But there always a check on ApplicationController like a below.

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :check_should_logout
```

I don't want to call `check_should_logout` on every request.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails before\_filter for specific actions in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061373/rails-before-filter-for-specific-actions-in-controller)

Comment: What is the goal of `check_should_logout` ?

Comment: Goal of check_should_logout is check users that session expired already.

There are users that session expired already in system.
I can force logout the users and check by check_should_logout method.

But, i don't want to call check_should_logout method on every requests(on controller).

Is there no way to use except or only actions on controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `only` or `except` options for [before_action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) filters in respective controller classes.

```
before_action :check_should_logout, only: [:action_1, :action_2]
```

OR

```
before_action :check_should_logout, except: [:action_1, :action_2]
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply. There are many actions. I think it seems to be inappropriate using except. If i can't solve this, i will check by batch every in 5 or 10 minuts and if logged the user(already session expired) call log_out function.

Answer (score 1):

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :check_should_logout, only: [:action1, :action_2]
```

or

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, :check_should_logout, except: [:action1, :action_2]
```

Instead of providing this in ApplicationController tou should provide this in respective controller.

Comment: Thank you for a reply. There are many actions. I think it seems to be inappropriate using except. If i can't solve this, i will check by batch every in 5 or 10 minuts and if logged the user(already session expired) call log_out function.